# Numerical issue with `foldl` and `foldr` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I have the following Haskell script which computes the function `f(x) = (2- x) - (2^3 - x^3/12)`

```
calc x = (x - (x ^ 3) / 12)
calc2 x = (calc 2) - (calc x)

calcList1 :: [Float] -> Float
calcList1 l = foldl (+) 0.0 (map calc2 l)

calcList2 :: [Float] -> Float
calcList2 l = foldr (+) 0.0 (map calc2 l)

test1 :: Float -> Float
test1 step = (calcList1 l) - (calcList2 l) 
    where 
        l = [0.0,step..2.0]
```

Function `calcList1` and `calcList2` run `calc2` function on each of list and then uses `foldl` and `foldr` respectively to sum the list. I was expecting both function to return the same answer but it does not.

```
*Main> test1 0.1
9.536743e-7
*Main> test1 0.01
2.2888184e-5
*Main> test1 0.001
2.4414063e-4
*Main> test1 0.0001
-3.7109375e-2
*Main>
```

Now I am confused. I can't see why numerical issues has to be involved here. Fold are essentially how ones collect each element which should be same in both cases, right?

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Keep in mind that for many applications, you don't actually need to use `Float`, but will be ok (or even better off) using `Rational` instead.

Comment: @kosmikus: yes, but for many applications, you don't actually need to use `Rational`, but will be ok (and better off, provided you know the quirks) using `Double` instead.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Of course there are use cases for `Float` and `Double`, but `Rational` is in my experience much less widely known, and I've seen many times that people unnecessarily jump to `Double` simply because a number has a dot in it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, the *order* in which floating point values are added is important. An entry point for own research could be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance . To summarize the basic caveat, in an oversimplified form:

Due to the limited number of significant bits, you have to assume something like

```
 100000000000000000.0 + 1.0 = 100000000000000000.0
```

in floating-point computations. Consequently, when computing

```
  100000000000000000.0 
+                  1.0 
- 100000000000000000.0
```

the result will be `0.0` - and thus, be different from

```
  100000000000000000.0 
- 100000000000000000.0
+                  1.0
```

where the result will be `1.0`.

Comment: More specifically in this case, `100000.0 + 0.1 + 0.1 + ... + 0.1` is different from `0.1 + 0.1 + ... + 0.1 + 100000.0` in LTR evaluation if the repeated additions of the low numbers yield something that is significant enough to show up when added to the large number.