# Is the distinction between foldr and foldl important for maps and sets?

Tags: haskell, fold, unordered

(This question applies more generally than to Haskell, but that's the language I'll use to state it.)

The distinction between `foldl` and `foldr` seems to depend on the fact that lists are ordered. That is, `foldl` and `foldl` collapse a list by applying a function to a starting value and the first or last element, then to the result of the first application and the second or second-to-last element, then the result of the second application to the third or third-to-last element, etc.

But the Data.Set and Data.Map libraries for Haskell define their own versions of `foldl` and `foldr`. For instance, for maps they are these:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Map k a -> b
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Map k a -> b -- I've swapped `a` and `b`
  -- in the second type signature to clarify the correspondence.
```

Maps and sets aren't ordered. Should I expect performance differences between the versions of `foldl` and `foldr` defined for sets and maps, or does `foldr f` do exactly the same thing as `foldl (flip f)`?

Comment: In Haskell though `foldl` can run lazily while `foldr` is strict. Apart from that there are many different use cases. Such as `foldr`ing items into a list could be much more efficient than `foldl`ing.

Comment: I cannot say anything about the performance difference, but there may be a difference in numerical results - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21454929/3182664) as an example.

Comment: @Redu That doesn't seem right -- for one, `take 5 (foldr (:) [] [1..])` terminates. What do you mean by "lazy" and "strict"?

Comment: @duplode Thanks for the head up. Right associative operations yielding strictness here was my false assumtion. Data.List explains this as; *Note that, since the head of the resulting expression is produced by an application of the operator to the first element of the list, foldr can produce a terminating expression from an infinite list.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maps and sets aren't ordered. Should I expect performance differences between the versions of foldl and foldr defined for sets and maps

If you refers the source code of [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Set.Internal.html#Set) or [`Data.Map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#Map), you will find that their elements are organized in binary tree:

```
data Map k a  = Bin !Size !k a !(Map k a) !(Map k a)
              | Tip 

data Set a    = Bin !Size !a !(Set a) !(Set a)
              | Tip
```

and the [`foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Set.Internal.html#foldr) of Set:

```
foldr f z = go z
  where
    go z' Tip           = z'
    go z' (Bin _ x l r) = go (f x (go z' r)) l
```

traverse the tree using depth-first search with order **right, current, left**, so when `foldr (+) 0` apply to follow tree:

```
                   1
                  / \
                 4   2
                      \
                       3
```

gives,

```
4 + (1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))
```

and [`foldl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/src/Data.Set.Internal.html#foldl)

```
foldl f z = go z
  where
    go z' Tip           = z'
    go z' (Bin _ x l r) = go (f (go z' l) x) r
```

with order **left, current, right** when apply `foldl (+) 0` to above tree, give:

```
((((0 + 4) + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

It show that `foldr` and `foldl` of Set equivalent to that apply to the list as:

```
foldr (+) 0 [4, 1, 2, 3] = 4 + (1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))
foldl (+) 0 [4, 1, 2, 3] = ((((0 + 4) + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

similar situation as `Data.Map` and don't repeat here.

Moreover, as we knew, `foldr` can apply to infinite list (but `foldl` cannot), for example:

```
take 10 $ foldr ((:) . sum) [] $ chunksOf 3 [1..] = [6,15,24,33,42,51,60,69,78,87]
```

(here [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.3/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) group the list like `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]...]`)

But how about when the tree has a path is infinite like:

```
                   1
                  / \
                 4   2
                      \
                       3
                        \
                         ...  <- infinite path
```

Does the `foldr` of Set behave as list as mentioned above? (I guess the answer is yes, you can check it for youself)

> does foldr f do exactly the same thing as foldl (flip f)?

**No**, As the source code as shown above:

```
foldr          = ... go (f x (go z' r)) l
```

and

```
foldl (flip f) = ... go (f x (go z' l)) r
```

The traversing order of tree is different, but the generic relation between `foldr` and `foldl` can be found in this post: [Defining foldl in terms of foldr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057923/defining-foldl-in-terms-of-foldr)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, sets and maps *are* ordered. That's why all the set and map functions have the `Ord` constraint on the key type. They're automatically ordered by the natural ordering of the element type. So if your set contains `{3, 5, 2, 1, 4}`, then Haskell will see it (for folding purposes) in the order `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

But let's forget about that for a minute. Let's assume we're in a perfect world where the data truly is unordered. Even then, the difference between `foldl` and `foldr` is significant. Suppose I have the set as before: `{3, 5, 2, 1, 4}`, and I want to perform some operation `.*` on it.

```
foldl (.*) 0 mySet = ((((0 .* 3) .* 5) .* 2) .* 1) .* 4
foldr (.*) 0 mySet = 3 .* (5 .* (2 .* (1 .* (4 .* 0))))
```

So even if the operation happens to be associative, the initial element is placed on the opposite side with a `foldl` versus a `foldr`. In fact, some operations *won't even work* if implemented using the wrong fold. Consider `toList`, which is defined in `Data.Foldable` to work on any `Foldable` object (including lists, maps, and sets). One possible implementation is

```
toList :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]
toList = foldr (:) []
```

If we were to try doing a `foldl`

```
definitelyWrong :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]
definitelyWrong = foldl (:) []
```

Then it doesn't even compile.

```
wrongfold.hs:5:25: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
        Actual type: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

This is because the folds associate differently and can work even with accumulation operations which take two differently-typed arguments, which is also apparent from the type signatures of the two

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

Note how the first argument is not `a -> a -> a` but actually has two different types, which indicates that the ordering definitely does matter.

Comment: I would argue that the `Ord` constraint is a consequence of using trees to store and index the data, and not related to the abstract data type itself. A fold over these data structures should only make sense if the function is both associative *and* commutative, so that the order in which the function is applied to the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: Great point about ordering. However, while `foldl (:) []` does not compile, `foldl (flip (:)) []` does -- congruent with the hypothesis in the question that `foldr f == foldl (flip f)`.